# Intricacies of the "super" keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, oop, inheritance, super

I have the following two classes in javascript: `Animals` & `Cat` (`Cat` extends `Animal`). Both classes will have an `introduce()` method; however, the `Cat` class needs some additional information in that method. Since I don't want to duplicate the entire method, I've thought of three ways of achieving this.

I've written out three approaches in comments under the introduce() method in the Cat class.

1. The first version doesn't work. This makes sense to me because it's using the wrong context.
2. The second version does work. This also makes sense to me because I'm using `call()` to explicitly set the context.
3. The third version does work. This **does not** make sense to me. How is this different from the first version? Does the `super` keyword somehow change the context?

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name, age, legs, species, status) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.legs = legs;
    this.species = species;
    this.status = status;
  }
  introduce() {
    return `Hello, my name is ${this.name} and I am ${this.age} years old and ${this.status}.`;
  }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  constructor(name, age, status) {
    super(name, age, 4, 'cat', status);
  }

  introduce() {
    // return Animal.prototype.introduce() + ' Meow meow!';
    // return Animal.prototype.introduce.call(this) + ' Meow meow!';
    // return super.introduce() + ' Meow meow!';
  }
}
```

Comment: "*How is this different from the first version?*" because the `super` keyword is created for exactly this kind of scenario? It wouldn't really make sense to have it if it doesn't really work for anything complex.

Comment: @CRice Well, `super` is used in other OOP languages to interact with the parent *definition* of a class. So if you have `someMethod(one) { super.someMerhod(one, "two"); }` you'd call the parent version of the method. In that code example, it's to to provide a single parameter override where the parent takes two parameters. So, the same OOP semantics are left in JS, so it doesn't diverge too much from traditional OOP. After all, `class` was introduced to mimic traditional OOP closer. So, `super.someMethod()` is sort of doing `this.__proto__.__proto__.someMethid.call(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

The third approach is the standard way to achieve this. It is the functionally the same as the 2nd version. In calls of the form `super[method]()`, the current object (`this`) is set as the context.

See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super).